# My Minecraft server lagged so I need help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was practicing water bucket mlg on my tlauncher minecraft server (aternos). Then one  of my friends gave himself 5000 water buckets which lagged the server completely can anyone help me get rid of all the buckets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if it have any errors in your console. If you see any "SEVERE" errors, this maybe be the cause of your lag.
2. Try and troubleshoot these errors

Answer (score 0):

Typing `/kill @e[type=minecraft:item]` will remove only the items dropped on the ground from the world.

Comment: Water_bucket isnt an entity, you probably meant to say minecraft:item

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. I didn't have my copy of the game at that moment to confirm it, I've changed it now.

Answer (score -1):

Type `/kill @e` in the chat which will remove all the water buckets that are dropped. Note that this command also kills every single entity in the world, including pets, mobs, armor stands, etc..

Comment: This also destroys every single entity in the world...